# Inserting into MySQL database with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I'm currently working on a school project and I need some help. I ran into a problem when trying to put the data I read from another IP address (using AJAX) into a MySQL database. I tried using node.js but because I'm calling the function when I press the button on a webpage it doesn't work... So any suggestions or tips on how to make node.js work.

ajax function:

```
function AddShoots() {
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "http://192.168.1.8",
    success: function (html) {
      for ($i = 0; $i < html.length; $i++) {
        console.log(html[$i]);
      }
    },
  });
}
```

The data I get and would like to insert into database:

[image: picture of console output]

EDIT: additional explanation

sorry for the HTML/CSS there was an error while copying. To clarify my endpoint I have a python image recognition program written on raspberry PI, the Raspberry PI server that is on the IP returns the numbers seen in the picture, I would like to insert the numbers into a MySQL database and I need help with how to do that because I only inserted data into tables with PHP before, but I can't do this in this case because I'm using AJAX (at least not with my knowledge) I hope this explains everything better.

Another edit:

A picture that might help with understanding (I'm super bad at explaining sorry English is not my primary language that's why I have bad expressions and a hard time explaining some stuff).

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to POST to your MySQL server directly? It's not clear what that endpoint is. The CSS and HTML are also completely irrelevant, and should be omitted for the sake of clarity, though it's worth noting your one `<div>` is mangled, you can see how the syntax highlighting identifies it as broken as it should end with `50%">` not `50%/"`.

Comment: CSS note: `positon` < that is a typo. It should read as `position`.

Comment: `<div style="positon:fixed;top:50%;left:7.5%;width:50%/"` < you didn't close that div properly. It's missing the `>` for it.

Comment: that looks like front end code (in the browser), that in turn will talk to backend (node.js?)  on the server, the node.js code in the back end then talks to the database also on the server.

Comment: If my answer wasn't helpful it's good etiquette here on SO to explain why before downvoting. It helps me give you a better answer.

Comment: @DanFletcher About your answer. I personally thought that your answer as well as it was written out, was just one long comment. What you should have done and I've done this before as well as other Stack members, was to write *"This is too long for a comment, let me explain...."*. It also didn't take into account the HTML/CSS issue(s) as pointed out in comments. In regards to those and if you're not an HTML/CSS guy and felt that what was mentioned in comments didn't belong in your answer, then something to the effect of *"Besides the HTML/CSS typos you made and were commented on already..."*.

Comment: There are (still) too many tags here which make this question unclear besides my "too broad" vote to close.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback! I'll see if I can fix the answer up to address those concerns.

Comment: @DanFletcher Welcome Dan. Side note about replying to a pinged (to you) comment. Please use what I did for you, with the `@username` method. I only saw your comment because I am "following" this question and got a notification for it. Had I not, then I would not have seen it. *Cheers*. Oh and I wouldn't worry too much about it now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you're getting your technologies mixed up a bit.

Lets clarify a few terms first:

**NodeJS**

Is a JavaScript **runtime** for **server-side** or **backend** code.

**Runtime**

An environment for code to execute like **NodeJS** or a web browser.

**Server-Side**

This refers to code running on a server. Could be PHP, Java, Python etc... or even JavaScript if you're using Node.

**Backend**

Usually means the same thing as "server-side" when people say "backend".

**Frontend**

In this context, "frontend" is referring to code being executed in a web browser.

**AJAX**

A style of HTTP request that a browser can use to send and fetch data without reloading the current page.

Now that we have that out of the way...

Node is a server-side runtime for JavaScript, so your JS code running in the browser has no way to talk to your Node code directly.

If you want to click a button in the browser and see data get written to your database you have to make an AJAX call to a url that your backend is listening to (known as an endpoint or a route).

It's a bit difficult to interpret your intentions from your example but I think you mean to send a POST to `http://192.168.1.8`. So you'll need a route configured in your Node app that can handle the AJAX request, and from there you can write the data to your database.

Of course you'll also need to pass the data with the request. That gets passed along with the options parameter in your `$.ajax(/* ... */)` call.

At a high level this is what I believe you're trying to achieve:
[image]

So basically your app should have at least two files:

1. `index.html` This will have your button as well as the JS code that fetches data from your Pi. This "front-end" JS will also have to send an AJAX request to your Node app.
2. `app.js` This will be your Node app. It will have to expose an endpoint that your front-end code can send data to. Inside the function of that endpoint, you'll handle writing the data to your database.

There's a library called Express that will help you make your endpoint. I recommend following their Getting Started guide: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/installing.html

**Update**

I see you updated your answer with a diagram. I assumed your mental model was probably exactly like that, which is why you're having a hard time.

When a user visits a url such as https://stackoverflow.com for example, the request doesn't go to the web browser. The request has to go through a server first. When you use Node, your app essentially is the server, and is responsible for returning the correct response.

In your case the response would be an HTML file like `index.html` for example.

That `index.html` is the webpage and it is going to contain your "front-end" JavaScript code, which can communicate to your Raspberry Pi server over HTTP to get that image data you're talking about.

JavaScript running in the browser has no way to communicate to a SQL database directly. So you have to send a request over the network to your Node service. Inside your backend application you can write the data to a MySQL database with the help of packages you can get from NPM. Here's an example of one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql

**Update 2**

It sounds like you're more comfortable using PHP. You can swap NodeJS out with PHP and my diagram would still represent what you want to achieve at a high level. The key difference is you won't have to figure out how to set up a "route".

With PHP you can just have a file named something like `SaveMyData.php`:

```php
<?php

// Get the body of the POST request
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');

// Decode the JSON string so you can work with it in PHP
$decodedData = json_decode($data);

// $decodedData is now an array of the data you sent from the browser
foreach($decodedData as $row) {
  // write the row to your database here
}
```

Then the "endpoint" (making some assumptions about how your serving your app) is just `http://localhost:8080/SaveMyData.php` and that becomes the URL you pass to your AJAX call from the browser.

Your AJAX request would look something like:

```js
function AddShoots() {
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST", // the post to your Pi I'm assuming?
    dataType: "json",
    url: "http://192.168.1.8",
    success: function (data) {
      $.ajax({
        method: "POST", // this is going out to your PHP backend
        dataType: "json",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/SaveMyData.php",
        data: data,
        success: function (response) {
          // do stuff with the response if you'd like
        })
      });
    },
  });
}
```

Tons of "best practices" are being violated here, but for the purposes of a school assignment this should get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: I just removed the downvote from earlier and as explained [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61762829/inserting-into-mysql-database-with-javascript#comment109248246_61762829) I left you under the OP's question and they have edited that part out. I apologize for this, personally now... feel that their question is too broad. Still, a good answer. That I still stand by ;-) *Cheers!*

Comment: Awesome I appreciate that. Cheers!

Comment: You're welcome Dan. About editing; meh... I wouldn't worry too much about that. What I said earlier in comments, no longer applies now.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Oh haha thanks! I just used Lucid Chart for that. At work we like to make diagrams like this all the time. Helps keep everyone on the same page and communicate ideas

Comment: Hello @DanFletcher thanks for the in-depth explanation and graphics I also made a quick sketch it might help us get on the same page.

Comment: @Anze Ok I see. I'll try to make my answer more clear. But your diagram is just not possible which is where I think you're confused.

Comment: yes probably... I'm super new to this so I'm still figuring stuff out. I'm learning so many languages at once I get confused about what goes where and how everything runs.

Comment: @Anze No worries! I updated my answer. Let me know if it helps you out more, or if you need more details.

Comment: @DanFletcher Hey thanks for going into details again, definitely helped me understand me everything. I tried using the option you provided in the second edit, but when the server goes to "http://localhost/matura/SaveData.php", nothing happens and all also when checking what happened with F12, the array and everything in it is undefined..

Comment: nevermind I had a problem with json data fixed it now, thanks for the help mate.

Comment: @Anze Awesome glad you got it working!